# Xcode ARKit image detection manual size adjustment

Tags: xcode, arkit

I have this image I'm going to detect that has a width of 18.3 cm and height of 19.5 cm however when I put these values Xcode automatically adjusts the other value i.e if width is 18,5 height becomes 16,547 is there a way to close the auto adjustment?

[image: xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you entered a **width** value for you real-environment image, Xcode automatically calculates a height value based on an **aspect ratio** of your `ARReferenceImage` that placed in `ARReferenceGroup` catalogue.

In case you want to use it programmatically implement this [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2942252-init):

```
init(_ image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation, physicalWidth: CGFloat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is automatically calculating the other dimension based on aspect ratio of your provided image file. You must provide reference image with the same aspect ratio as its physical size. You can easily resize it or crop to match your dimensions.